# Java Swing: Using a Document Listener to Handle the Return Key

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentlistener

I have a document listener that works just fine. However, I'd like to add some functionality to it so that when the user hits the Enter key, the focus shifts to another object. I can't figure out how to trap this. Here is my code:

```
txtNum1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                setAnswer(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                setAnswer(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                setAnswer(e);
            }

            private void setAnswer(DocumentEvent e) {
                if (txtNum1.getText().equals("")) {
                    num1 = 0;
                } else {
                    num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtNum1.getText());
                }
                calcAnswer();
                System.out.println(e); //trying to output the event 'Enter'
            }
```

I can do this with a key listener, but I've been scolded on this site before about using that approach, so I'm trying to learn this the correct way.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Per the suggestions below, I added the following code, but it seems to have no effect. Can anyone see what I am missing? Thanks!

```
/* If the user hits the Enter key, we want the focus to shift to
 * the next text field */
txtNum1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        txtNum2.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to admit, I would've used a key listener to listen for the key events that have nothing to do with the document itself (return, escape, function keys etc.) ... Guess I need an answer too now!

Comment: If you are not using a JTextField then the solution would be to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for the Enter key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a JTextfield, you can trap the `Enter` key simply by adding an `ActionListener`. It will get fired when the users types <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: @camickr No problem. Sometimes it just happens that we type the same answer almost simultaneously.